# Regex to validate numbers 0-100 with up to two decimal places

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I know it would be easier to just use the php is_numeric function, but what i'm trying to do is create a regular expression, mostly for learning regex, to test test scores. The range can be 0-100, but can have 2 decimal places. This is what I have so far and its not working.

```
  if (preg_match("^([0-9]){2,3})(.[0-9]{2})?$([0-9]{1})?$", $quiz1))
    {
        echo "match";
    }
    else {
        $error = true;
    }
```

If I'm thinking correctly the literal meaning:

start of string find characters 0-9, for two places. 
optional end of string decimal and find characters 0-9, for two places.
optional end of string find characters 0-9, for 1 place.

Comment: Your regex has syntax errors and misuse of metacharacters. If you are going to use regex (and I hightly recommend that you do), you need to spend some time learning the (cryptic) syntax. i.e. Learn the metacharacters (which are different inside and outside character classes BTW), and practice, practice, practice with an interactive tool such as [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) or [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/). There are excellent free tutorials that will get you off to a good start, e.g. [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
 /^(?:100|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

- ^ - beginning of string
- (?:100|\d{1,2}) - non-capturing group, 100 or 0-99
- (?:.\d{1,2})? - optional non-capturing group (.# or .##)
- $ - end of string

Results:

> php > $tests = array(0, 5, 10, 50, 100, 99.5, 75.43, 75.436, 101);
>
> php > foreach ($tests as $test) { print $test . " - " .  preg_match("/^(?:100|\d{1,2})(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/", $test) . "\n"; }
>
> 0 - 1
>
> 5 - 1
>
> 10 - 1
>
> 50 - 1
>
> 100 - 1
>
> 99.5 - 1
>
> 75.43 - 1
>
> 75.436 - 0
>
> 101 - 0
>
> 75F43 - 0

Yours doesn't work even when I add the slashes and remove the extra `)`.

> php > foreach ($tests as $test) { print $test . " - " . 
>   preg_match("/^([0-9]{2,3})(.[0-9]{2})?$([0-9]{1})?$/", $test) . "\n"; }
>   0 - 0
>
> 5 - 0
>
> 10 - 1
>
> 50 - 1
>
> 100 - 1
>
> 99.5 - 0
>
> 75.43 - 1
>
> 75.436 - 0
>
> 101 - 1
>
> 75F43 - 1

Comment: Yours will also match `00` and `100.99`.

Comment: I'm looking for something close to this but for me 100.99 is not acceptable. It really has to be between 0 and 100 inclusive. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Surround your expression with `/` characters

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 0):

gpojd's answer is correct. However, here's why your regex isn't working.

First of all, you want the first $ inside the ()'s. Because otherwise it will need to match the end of the string, and then later after that the end of the string again, which is of course impossible.

Second, the dot character needs to become \. because a dot by itself matches any character, but you want an actual dot. Lastly, you need delimiters, like someone else suggested. Here's what your regex matches:

first, two or three digits, mandatory.
Then, any character followed by two digits, optionally.
Then, the end of the string, mandatory.
Then, one digit, optionally.
Then, the end of the string again, mandatory.

Since you're a programmer, it can be hard to get used to the way of thinking with regular expressions; you're used to thinking in terms of if-else statements but regular expressions don't really work that way.

Again, the option above is good enough but if I were to write a regex for this I'd put:

```
/^100(.00)?|([1-9]?[0-9])(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
```

So, either 100 followed by an optional .00, or: first, an optional nonzero digit and then a mandatory digit (those make the numbers 0 to 99), then optionally a dot followed by two digits.

Comment: But the OP said `0` is valid.  Also, this won't match `99.5` (which is probably valid), and it *will* match `100.99` (which is almost certainly *not* valid).

Comment: you're right, 0 should be valid, it isn't in my regex; 100.99 shouldn't match. I'll edit. But if I understand the OP correctly then it should either have no dot and digits, or it should have a dot and two digits.

Comment: I think that's just poor wording in the question; the title says "up to two digits".  (Which implies `0.` should pass, too, but I'm not going there :D )